# BlockMissingException when trying to read in files from my Hadoop Cluster in KNIME

Tags: docker, hadoop, hdfs, knime

I am currently trying to read in a csv-file from my Hadoop cluster in KNIME and keep getting this exception org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockMissingException - Could not obtain block: BP-788889731-172.18.0.7-1689243803391:blk_1073741840_1016 file=/data/openbeer/breweries/breweries.csv.

My Hadoop Cluster runs locally with Docker.
I successfully connected my Hadoop Cluster with KNIME.
But whenever I try to read in a simple CSV File which I stored in my HDFS File System it can't seem to be able to access the file. Which is really weird cause KNIME seems to be able to see my HDFS File structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Uhx.png)

as you can see right here.

I already went through some post with similar problems and tried several solutions including some where corrupt files where included as the cause of this exception but I already checked through commands and my nodes seem to be healthy.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTbHY.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't seem to access the CSV files in my HDFS Structure through KNIME even though they are easily accessable through the PowerShell. My datanodes and namenodes seem healthy and have been able to access each other in the shell.